# Google Maps Geolocation API is not giving valid responses

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-geolocation

I have a free trial account for Google Maps Geolocation API, which comes with quota of 100 requests/day.

A few weeks ago I was able to successfully send JSON requests with cell tower info and get JSON responses with accurate coordinates. Today, I'm seeing very strange behavior. On the machine/IP I used when it worked before, sending a request with widely varying cell tower info gives me the same exact coordinates in response (as if it is cached). On another machine/IP I haven't used, I get a 404 "location not found" response even though the cell location definitely exists.

I checked and I am not exceeding my quota and still have 18 days left on my free trial. Is there another restriction I'm not aware of? Has anyone seen this odd behavior before?

*Update:* 
I'm sending JSON requests through a custom Java application using Apache HTTP; there is no browser to allow/deny permission. I am correctly handling responses/errors, although that is outside the scope of this issue. I know it worked as expected 2 weeks ago, giving responses with and without location coordinates depending on the cell tower info. It no longer works using the same setup, or a new setup from a remote server (different IP).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of reasons for this to happen.

Did your browser requested to allow or deny the permission to use the location data? If you denied than it may give a 404, other than that even if there is a firewall restricting the location access it may give a 404.

Working with geolocation and GPS enabled applications, you should assume that for some cases, the geolocation is going to fail and you should build an exception handling component that does not fail if errors do occur with geolocation. Your application should continue functioning even if the current GPS location was not correctly fetched due to an error or a user denying permission for the browser to provide the GPS location.

These amy be the probable cause, but to be very specific you need to provide additional details.

Comment: I'm not sure which additional details to add, but see my response that I appended to my question.